# Creating different views for different user type on login (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am in need of help creating different views for different user type (Students, Teacher, Admin, etc.). After successful login, I want to redirect the users to their specific view. Currently, I am able to verify their user type and login credentials directly from the database, if its successful, it redirects to the default layout view.

This is my login.aspx for the login form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LoginQuery
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=[Connection String]";
        }

        protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + userType.SelectedValue + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
            con.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect(url: "http://localhost:56061/");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(ds, "Person");

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
                }
                else
                {

                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
                }
            }
        }

        protected void UserType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
            {
                if (userType.SelectedValue == "Student")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Teacher")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/teacher.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/counselor.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Parent")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/parent.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Principal")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/principal.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/admin.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use response.redirect to my localhost page.

Comment: Don't post your actual connection string here. Also you are **wide** open to SQL injection attacks, use parameterized SQL queries instead. If this is anything other than a school project etc, never, ever and I mean ever store passwords as plain text. You should be salting and one way hashing them. Even if it is a learning of project it wont hurt you to store passwords correctly.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm pretty new to c# and not really sure how to implement parameterized SQL queries. How would I go about that? Mind if you show an example?

Comment: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: After Successful Login you can retrieve data about the user including usertypeId , store it in a session  use them for permission and redirection